# Internal server error 500 for all requests to Google Ads API

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

Here is my code in Node JS.

```
 var bearerToken = 'Bearer '+ access_token;

 var options = {
                 url: 'https://googleads.googleapis.com/v1/customers/'+accountid+'/googleAds:search',
                 headers: {
                       'Authorization': bearerToken,
                       'Accept': 'application/json',
                       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                       'login-customer-id': '123-456-7890',
                       'developer-token': 'XXX_XXXXXXXXXXX'
                     },
                     form: { 'query': 'SELECT campaign.id, campaign.name FROM campaign ORDER BY campaign.id' }


                   };


                   request.post(options, function(err, response) {
                       console.log(response);
                   });
```

I keep getting the below error

```
body: '{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 500,\n    "message": "Internal error encountered.",\n    "status": "INTERNAL"\n  }\n}\n' }
```

500 error code means the error is from Google. Is this the case or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After breaking my head with multiple iterations. Finally, I figured out that the problem was with the `developer-token`. I had to generate a new `developer-token` and change `form` to `json`. It's working fine now.

Here is the final working code

```
var bearerToken = 'Bearer '+ access_token;

var options = {
             url: 'https://googleads.googleapis.com/v1/customers/'+accountid+'/googleAds:search',
             headers: {
                   'Authorization': bearerToken,
                   'Accept': 'application/json',
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                   'developer-token': 'XXX_XXXXXXXXXXX'
                 },
                 json: { 'query': 'SELECT campaign.id, campaign.name FROM campaign ORDER BY campaign.id' }


               };


               request.post(options, function(err, response) {
                   console.log(response);
               });
```